# Is there a way to automate an LLDB command upon file save in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es

I'm developing an OpenGL ES app for iOS. I'd love to skip the whole rebuild cycle when I just edit the fragment shaders. Ideally, I want Xcode to re-upload the shader code to the device and invoke a few LLDB `expr` commands.

To achieve the same effect, I could, for instance, just break before the render cycle and manually run a bunch of `exprs` with copied and pasted GLSL code, but that's tedious and fragile, so that kills the ergonomic win over rebuilding the whole app.

Whenever I save a file with a certain extension, I'd love Xcode to overwrite it in the bundle on the device, and run a scripted sequence of LLDB commands. Note that shaders here are not really the key point: those could easily be static images or anything not getting to the resulting binary directly.

Comment: Hi, @rmaddy! Thank you for your input. Although the question indeed mentions OpenGL ES, I don't think the tag is relevant: as stated in the last paragraph, instead of the OpenGL-ES-specific asset, it could be any other asset. I'll leave your edit as is, but you might want to roll it back not to confuse future readers.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking for is to more or less be able to hot load files?

Comment: @MobileBen, exactly. Thank you for a concise way to put it.

Comment: I've never tried this, but you could always write a script to copy over updated files to the bundle. Then in lldb, execute a function which reloads. You just need to know where the actual container is, which you can always get by outputting it when the app launches. Obviously would one work on the simulators.